# Install git or update git without apt-get or yum

Tags: linux, git, git-svn, yum, apt-get

I have some linux boxes that do not allow me to use yum to install packages. Instead I need to download the zip or tar and then use a package manager to install the items on my linux boxes.

When you go to the [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/download/linux) page, the only way they provide to install git is to use yum, apt-get, etc from the command line.

Why is there not just a zip file?
Where can I find the package to install?
Has anyone else had this same issue?

Comment: What type of systems are these? What do you mean `use a package manager to install the [zip or tar]`? `yum` **is** a package manager.

Comment: We use Opsware to install everything on our machines. So I just need the zip or tar to install it. Yum is locked down.

Comment: Can you download the [git .deb file](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/git) and install it with `dpkg -i`?

Comment: You need a special opsware zip/tar then? Are they just /-rooted archives of files? I don't know opsware at all but this sounds like an odd way of doing things to me. That said, I doubt you'll find packages like that of most software.

Comment: I just need the zip of the git install contents. I can lay it all out on the server myself.

Comment: What you're talking about isn't a normal way of installing things on a Linux box. If you *really* want a manual install, it's probably best to clone the git source repo, and build from source https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/INSTALL . That being said, if you *insist* on installing a pre-built binary without your package manager, you can always download the Slackware package for git... Slackware packages are just tarballs with the binary blobs inside.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before. I tried to install git from source and it works.

Intalling these packages first:

```
curl
autoconf
zlib-devel
openssl-devel
perl
cpio
expat-devel
gettext-devel
```

Getting the GIT scm source code:

git-latest.tar.gz

Compiling the GIT scm from source

```
tar xzvf git-latest.tar.gz
cd git-{date} // edit it
autoconf
./configure --with-curl=/usr/local
make
make install
```

Comment: careful with that git zip link.. it looks sketchy.  You could just download the source from github: https://github.com/git/git/archive/master.zip

Comment: Thanks. It's just an example.